# Searched result is not rendered in view page in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

views/feedbacks/searchfeedback.html.erb :

My Search Form :

```
 <%= form_tag(search_feedback_feedback_path(:id), :method => :get) do %>
     <%= text_field_tag :token_no %>
     <%= submit_tag 'Search' %>
 <% end %>
```

app/config/routes.rb file :

```
resources :feedbacks do   
  member do
    get :search_feedback
  end
end

match '/feedbackresult' => 'feedbacks#searchedfeedback'
```

in feedbacks_controller.rb file :

```
def search_feedback
  if params[:token_no]
    @result_feedback = Feedback.find_by_token(params[:token_no])
    redirect_to feedbackresult_path
  end    
end
```

views / feedbacks/ searchedfeedback.html.erb :

```
Your Result found  :  <%= @result_feedback.name %>
```

Here I am Getting following Error :

```
NoMethodError in Feedbacks#searchedfeedback

Showing C:/Users/PROJ/app/views/feedbacks/searchedfeedback.html.erb where line #1 raised:
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

Comment: `find_by_token` probably isn't finding anything.

Comment: find_by_token is working absolutely fine(as token is the name of one column in feedbacks table), even I have inspected the same using logger.info(@result_feedback.name).

issue is just with rendering.

Comment: Then why are you getting the error `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` ? Perhaps there is some other variable to which you are sending the `:name` message?

Comment: Oh nevermind. You're using `redirect_to`. `redirect_to` sends a `301` redirect response to the browser. Your environment reloads, and your instance variables are no longer available.

Comment: In controller using logger.info I have inspected and it's really returning proper result, but I am not sure why it's not rendering the same in the view page. 

check my 1st comment under the answered section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you set the instance variable `@result_feedback`, you are redirecting using `redirect_to`"

```
def search_feedback
  if params[:token_no]
    @result_feedback = Feedback.find_by_token(params[:token_no])
    redirect_to feedbackresult_path # <-- the current request is over!
  end
end
```

`redirect_to` sends a a `301` response with a `Location` header.

After your controller action calls `redirect_to`, the current request ends and all of your instance variables are not available to the request that the browser performs as per the HTTP specification for `301 Redirect`. This is part of the HTTP request cycle.

You probably want to simply do:

```
render :feedbackresult
```

Which will simply render the template for the `feedbackresult` action.

Comment: Bingo that did my job !!!
But my result page is "searchedfeedback".
Hence I should use render :searchedfeedback

Comment: But in search functionality it's always advisable to render the searched result in the same page itself rather than creating a new page. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try only returning it if @result_feedback isn't `nil` - you can do it like this:

```
Your Result found  :  <%= @result_feedback.name if @result_feedback %>
```

Comment: Well, on trying above code nothing was printed my view page, which indicates @result_feedback to be null.

But before the redirect_to feedbackresult_path, I have used logger.info(@result_feedback.name) which is printing fetched name in development.log file. 

I am not sure, where it's wrong!

Comment: think that should be a comment on the other answer :)  he's right btw!

Comment: yeah correct, I meant to add comment on that answer by mistake. 
In other way found bug/may be feature in stackoverflow that I can't delete my comment ! :p

Comment: you should be able to hover over your answer and an `x` will appear to the right of the time stamp next to your name

Comment: Got it, dax ! Magic of Ajax. :D